# websocket-sharp Getting data result from client

Tags: websocket-sharp

```
protected override void OnMessage (MessageEventArgs e)
{
Send("Testing");
//Console.writeline("result data getting from client");

}
```

Hi,

I'm trying to do get a data while sending message. On above i added a row which is getting data from m client. Right now i can only send message. What i am want is for example i will send two numbers and sum them on client side and return that result on above that line i just wrote. //Console.writeline("result data getting from client");

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

        Send("Received");
    }
```